# Why Ghidra doesn't load the disassembly correctly while radare2 does?

Tags: disassembly, ghidra

I'm trying to get the disassembly of a very small binary file available [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsYP2RqBWCWrokQmsi4oN2igDK2m?e=fnrfXV). This file is cropped from part of another executable binary.

When I open it with `r2` it automatically recognizes the architecture and can provide me with the diassembly:

[image]

With Ghidra however, it cannot find the architecture automatically and I have to manually specify the language:

[image]

Even then, I'm getting the following as the disassembly:

[image]

I'm very surprised by how poor NSA's Ghidra is performing in such scenario compared to the open source radare2. Can someone describe what's going on and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have just raw bytes without proper headers tools might not know how to process as the code might not start from offset `0`. They could try to analyze the bytes to detect if there's code, data or something else but you might also get some false-positives.

In your case, you instruct `r2` to display those bytes as code (`pd - print disassembly`) and it does not recognize any architecture as it has x86 by default. You would get the same when you open no file (`r2 -` and then `e asm.arch`)

In Ghidra you selected the architecture manually and to "force" the tool to do the same as your `pd` in radare2 just press <kbd>D</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

Paweł Łukasik is correct.

Disassembling the code fragment using Ghidra can be done in 3 steps:

1. Selecting the architecture (which you have already done)
2. Highlighting the bytes to disassemble

[image: Highlight and press D]

3. Press "D" as Paweł stated or right click and select "disassemble"

[image: disassembled fragment]